# Proof the existence of a certain bilinear form on the vector space $V/T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces, bilinear-form

> Let $V$ be a vector space (over a field $K$) together with a symmetric bilinear form $\langle-,-\rangle$, and let $T\subseteq V$ be the orthogonal complement (since I'm not a native speaker, I hope this is the right term) with
> $$T :=\{v\in V|\ \langle u,v\rangle = 0 \text{ for every } u \in V\}.$$
> Show that there exists a symmetric bilinear form $\langle-,-\rangle'$ on $V/T$ (this is the vector space that includes the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation defined by $T$ on $V$) such that
> $$\langle[u], [v]\rangle' =\langle u, v\rangle,$$
> for every $u,v\in V$.

Yeah, that's the task, and I have to admit that I have certain difficulties with proving the existence of certain objects - never got into the right way of thinking for that I guess. Therefore, I would be glad to receive only a small hint so that I can try solving it on my own.

The problem is that I don't even know where to start from here. I know there exists a canonical projection

$$f:\ V\ \longrightarrow\ V/T,$$

with $f$ being linear. Shall I use this information and somehow proof the equation

$$\langle-,-\rangle=\langle-,-\rangle',$$
like I tried here:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question already presents to you what the bilinear form should be; it is defined as
$$\langle[u],[v]\rangle':=\langle u,v\rangle.$$
It remains to verify that this indeed defines a symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: ... which means that I have to proof that <[u], [v]>' is linear in the first and in the second component?

Comment: ...and $\langle[u],[v]\rangle'=\langle[v],[u]\rangle'$, and that it is well-defined in the first place.

Comment: But what about the proof that <[u], [v]>' = <u, v> actually holds? When I proof that <-,->' does indeed define a symmetric bilinear form, I also have to make sure that <-,->' = <-,-> for every u, v in V, right?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. How is $\langle[u],[v]\rangle'$ defined, according to you?

Comment: For me, <[u], [v]>' is not defined yet - but as I said, I do have certain difficulties with these type of tasks. I mean, you defined <-,->' := <-,->, but why are you allowed to do so? Isn't this actually part of the proof? How do you make sure that both bilinear forms actually give you the same values for the same input? I guess I have lack of basic understanding right there.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to prove that there exists a symmetric bilinear form <-,->' such that <-.-> = <-,->', don't I? Therefore, I would first try to prove that <-,->' is actually a symmetric bilinear form, and secondly I would try to prove  that ... uhm, yeah, the equation from above holds for a certain bilinear form. I mean, I have to make sure that the dot product of [v] and [u] actually equals the dot product of v and u, haven't I? Even if <-,->' would be symmetric and bilinear - I can't assure that the dot products equal each other. At least I think so.

Comment: *"I would first try to prove that $\langle-,-\rangle'$ is actually a symmetric bilinear form..."*. Then what is $\langle-,-\rangle'$ here?

Comment: The fact that $\langle[-],[-]\rangle'=\langle-,-\rangle$ must hold already tells you precisely what this symmetric bilinear form should be; it leaves no room for it to be anything else. You just need to check that this is a well-defined function on $V/T$, and that it is a symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: Unfortunately, I find it hard to tell in which direction you're trying to push me, although I really appreciate your efforts. I can't tell what <-,->' is. (of course I would assume it equals <-,->, but I would'nt be able to tell why)

Comment: The question *tells you* that's what it is. If you are asked to show that there is a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ holds for all $x$ and $y$, then surely $f=g$.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, although it seems a little bit counter-intuitive to me. (which may be caused by a lack of basic understanding) Could you describe what a task may look like that actually expects me to  not only show certain properties like symmetry or bilinearity but also that a equation like the above actually holds? (so that I have to make sure that both functions really are identical)

Comment: If your function is defined by some other property, and it being identical is a consequence of that. I'm not familiar enough with bilinear forms to know of an example. But in this question, part of the *definition* of your function is that it is identical to a given function.

Comment: It was a bad example though, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really gave me some important insights. Maybe I'll start another topic with the explicit question for other examples of these kind of tasks - such that I avoid feeling overwhelmed in the future. Oh, and about the function being well-defined: When [v] = [u], then <[v], [v]> = <[u], [u]> simply because [v] and [u] have the same elements (following from the definition of an equivalence class), and that already means that the function is well-defined, doesn't it?

Comment: Showing that $\langle-,-\rangle'$ is well-defined means showing that it does not depend on which representative you choose for the equivalence classes. So if $u,u',v,v'\in V$ are such that $[u]=[u']$ and $[v]=[v']$, then
$$\langle[u],[v]\rangle'=\langle[u'],[v']\rangle',$$
should hold. And you're welcome :) Consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer if you found it helpful ;) Then the question can be considered closed.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can handle the rest. :-) Have a nice day! I accepted your answer, but it seems like I'm not allowed to give you an upvote since I didn't earn enough reputation yet.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again, but I have a short question about my prove of linearity in both components of <-,->'. Since I've been working under the premise that <-,->' := <-,->, and since I've proven the well-definedness of <-,->' such that it doesn't matter which representatives I use, the proof for (for addition) should go something like this: <[v] + [u], [w]>' = <v + u, w>' (since <-,->' is well-defined) = <v + u, w> (since <-,->' = <-,->) = <v, w> + <u, w> (since <-,-> is bilinear) = <v, w>' + <u, w>' = <[v], [w]>' + <[u], [w]>'. Is that correct? :-)

Comment: Seems correct to me. I'd write the first step somewhat differently as
$$\langle[v]+[u],[w]\rangle'=\langle[v+u],[w]\rangle'=\langle v+u,w\rangle,$$
because $\langle-,-\rangle'$ is a function on $V/T$, not on $V$. But yes, your approach is correct.

Comment: Thank you! The scalar multiplication and symmetry should follow the same way. But I have still problems with proving the well-defindness of <-,->', but isn't this somehow trivial? Let's assume <[u], [v]>' != <[u'], [v']>'. Then there must be a w in [u]' or there must be a w in [v]' such that w is not in [u] or such that w is not in [v]. (such the result could'nt be the same) But since the equivalence classes are identical, this cannot be true, therefore I proved the statement by contradiction. At least this would be my approach.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in notation in your answer. Are $[u']$ and $[u]'$ the same? You want to show that if you have $u,u',v,v'\in V$ with $[u]=[u']$ and $[v]=[v']$ then $\langle[u],[v]\rangle'=\langle[u'],[v']\rangle'$.

Comment: I edited a picture with my thoughts in the main post, that should be clearer then.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. Why must there be such a $w\in[v']$?

Comment: P.S. at what point have you used that $\langle v,t\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ and all $t\in T$? Or the fact that you're taking the quotient with respect to this particular $T$?

Comment: When I assume that <[u], [v]> != <[u]', [v]'>, then this can only be true when either [u] != [u]' or [v] != [v]', can't it? And this is exactly the case when there is a w in [u] that's not in [u]', otherwise the values must be the same, right? But it's true that I haven't used any of of these properties that you mentioned nonetheless.

Comment: What does it mean for this map to be well-defined? You need to check that it is independent of the representative you choose for an equivalence class.

Comment: I thought a while about that, but I simply don't see how I have to solve this. Do you have a clearer hint for me?